# Add items to listbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add few items to a list box from a text box  using javascript. but the problem is as soon as I am adding the items, it gets visible in the list box for a second and then gets deleted. Any solution for this?

I am adding items from TextBox4  to ListBox1

```
function AddToList() {

    // Create an Option object        

    var opt = document.createElement("option");

    // Add an Option object to List Box

    document.getElementById("ListBox1").options.add(opt);
    opt.text = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
    opt.value = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
    document.getElementById("ListBox1").options.add(opt);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, Need to add

```
return false;
```

at the end of the function.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("ListBox1").options.add(opt); // remove this line
opt.text = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
opt.value = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
document.getElementById("ListBox1").options.add(opt);
```

As you're appending an `<option>` which has no `value` or `text`.

Comment: Still not working. Same thing is happening, items are getting added and within a second they are disappearing.